# How to stop falling objects from appearing in mid-air on HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, collision

[ETA] for better clarification:
I'm currently learning to code a HTML canvas game (items catching and dodging) using Javascript for a class project and I'm having problem with getting the objects falling down from top of the canvas.
The problem I'm having currently is occasionally (one might need to reload the game several times to notice this phenomenon) an object 'jumps' out of a random point **inside** the canvas where it should be thrown back up to the negative y coordinate area (aka. out of sight) and fall down again from there after collision detection.

So for example, when a giftbox is caught or disappears off the bottom edge, it should be thrown back up to the top of the canvas. However, sometimes it pops out of a random point in the middle, or near the bottom edge of the canvas instead, which is not at all what I intended.

I figure there must be a logical error with the code I write, but I have been trying several fixes and looking up answers for the past few days without any success.

I guess the problem must lie in the part of the code where I do collision detection:

```
function fallAgain() {
    
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * objectArray.length);
        if (objectArray[i].y > canvas.height) {

            [objectArray[i], objectArray[r]] = [objectArray[r], objectArray[i]];
            objectArray[r].y = randomY();
            objectArray[r].x = randomX();
            
            // this loop is to check if two randomly generated items overlap
            for (let idx = 1; idx < 3; idx++) {
                if (Math.abs(objectArray[idx].x - objectArray[idx-1].x) <= 10
                    && Math.abs(objectArray[idx].y - objectArray[idx-1].y) <=10) {
                    objectArray[idx].y += 30;
                    objectArray[idx].x += 20;
                    
                }
            }
            
            if (objectArray[r].status == 1 
                || objectArray[r].status == 3 
                || objectArray[r].status == 4) {
                lives--;
            }
        }
    }
}

function hitOrMissed() {
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * objectArray.length);
        if (objectArray[i].x + objectArray[i].w > kid.x + 3
            && objectArray[i].x + 3 < kid.x + kid.w
            && objectArray[i].y + objectArray[i].h > kid.y
            && objectArray[i].y < kid.y + kid.h - 3) {
                
                [objectArray[i], objectArray[r]] = [objectArray[r], objectArray[i]];
                objectArray[r].y = randomY();
                objectArray[r].x = randomX();
                
                for (let idx = 1; idx < 3; idx++) {
                if (Math.abs(objectArray[idx].x - objectArray[idx-1].x) <= 10
                    && Math.abs(objectArray[idx].y - objectArray[idx-1].y) <=10) {
                    objectArray[idx].y += 30;
                    objectArray[idx].x += 20;
                    
                }
            }
                
                if (objectArray[r].status == 1) {
                    score++;
                } else if (objectArray[r].status == 0) {
                    lives--;
                } else if (objectArray[r].status == 4) {
                    if (lives < 2) {
                        lives++;
                    } else {
                        lives += 0;
                        score += 2;
                    }
                } else if (objectArray[r].status == 3) {
                    score += 5;
                }
        }
    }
}
```

So far I've tried merging the fallAgain and hitOrMissed functions, but the problem persists

And here's my Codepen with the full code:
[Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/Maskros/pen/LYzmYER)

If someone could please help me identify where I've made it wrong and a pointer or guideline as to what I should do to fix the problem I'd really appreciate it. I'm not sure if this piece of information is of any help, but I'm just a beginner at Javascript with no prior coding experience and I've only learned the basics (I haven't touched constructor and Object-oriented Programming yet).
Thank you so much in advance for your help!

Comment: You need to isolate the problem more. And you need to compress your question down to solve the specific problem. It's nice to hear about your problem but I couldn't really understand what your actual *question* was.

Comment: @birgersp: Thank you for the suggestion. I've edited the question and filtered out unnecessary information.

Comment: Add some `console.log` to debug that code ... no one better than you to know what your code is doing ... Only thing seems fishy is your "loop to check if two randomly generated items overlap" ... why are you doing the `y += 30` that is a weird jump, maybe subtract (aka. out of sight) instead of add